# How to configure Resharper so that it "allows" having underscore in method names?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, nunit, naming-conventions, resharper

I'm using NUnit with Resharper.

For normal methods I'm using Pascal casing convention e.g. MethodName().

I'd like to use the below pattern for my test methods because they become more readable as their names would be long, however, Resharper complains that the pattern should be without "_".

```cs
[Test]
public void LoginRegisterPage_WithValidEmailAddress_ShouldSendReminderEmail()
{
}
```

How to configure Resharper so that it allows having underscore in method names without throwing warnings?

I went to Resharper > Options > Languages > C# > C# Naming Style > Override Custom Settings / Advanced Settings and added an option to have "_" but what happened is that it requires now that all my methods to be named well whereas I just like to be able to allow this syntax.

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: From looking at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-116772 It appears that resharper won't allow regular expressions for Naming Style.  If it did you could do (_)* to allow 0 or more underscores.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to Resharper options, c# (or any other language supported) and naming style. 
You can select "Method" and have the "all_lower" option selected.

If you add it as another option it should not give you any trouble.